# How can i merge a object from other documents and put in a specific one in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection organized like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ea0842fb7c525173bd20e78"),
        "vehicleid" : 32040,
        "points" : {
                "direction" : 135,
                "latitude" : -3.744851,
                "longitude" : -38.545571,
                "odometer" : 55697826,
                "routecode" : 0,
                "speed" : 3,
                "deviceid" : 134680,
                "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T02:59:59Z")
        }
}
```

And I need to create one document that stores all the "points" objects from documents with the same "vehicleid", like:

```
 {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ea0842fb7c525173bd20e78"),
            "vehicleid" : 32040,
            "points" :[ {
                    "direction" : 135,
                    "latitude" : -3.744851,
                    "longitude" : -38.545571,
                    "odometer" : 55697826,
                    "routecode" : 0,
                    "speed" : 3,
                    "deviceid" : 134680,
                    "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T02:59:59Z")
            }, {    
                    "direction" : 135,
                    "latitude" : -3.235521,
                    "longitude" : -37.5122571,
                    "odometer" : 8456763,
                    "routecode" : 0,
                    "speed" : 4,
                    "deviceid" : 134680,
                    "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T05:35:59Z") }
]
    }
```

**Any Ideas???**

Comment: you should look at $push operator. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/

Answer (score 0):

you can aggregate pipeline

1- if you need to keep the original document _id, the results will be as you mentioned in the question

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {} // add your search filter here
  },
  {
    $group: { // this is to group all the points objects related to some vehicle 
      _id: "$vehicleid",
      originalId: {
        $first: "$_id" // to keep the _id of the original document, if you don't need it, you can omit this part
      },
      points: {
        $addToSet: "$points" // push the points objects without any duplication, if you just need to push them and duplication does not matter for you, user $push instead of $addToSet
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { // this project step is used to get the original _id of the document, if you don't need it, you can omit all this project step
      _id: "$originalId",
      vehicleid: "$_id",
      points: 1
    }
  }
])
```

check this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HEs4I4KtvS1)

> Note that this will get the first document Id only, if many documents have the same vehicle Id, the _id you'll get back belongs to the first document, I suggest you to go for option 2

2- If you just need the vehicle id with the points without the original document _id

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$vehicleid",
      points: {
        $addToSet: "$points"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

check this too [Mongo Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vvj7mXYkBhW)

Answer (score 0):

Using these two ***input documents***:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "vehicleid" : 32040,
        "points" : {
                "direction" : 135,
                "latitude" : -3.744851,
                "longitude" : -38.545571,
                "odometer" : 55697826,
                "routecode" : 0,
                "speed" : 3,
                "deviceid" : 134680,
                "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T02:59:59Z")
        }
},
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "vehicleid" : 32040,
        "points" : {
                    "direction" : 135,
                    "latitude" : -3.235521,
                    "longitude" : -37.5122571,
                    "odometer" : 8456763,
                    "routecode" : 0,
                    "speed" : 4,
                    "deviceid" : 134680,
                    "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T05:35:59Z")
        }
}
```

And, the ***aggregation query***:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  {
      $group: {
          _id: { "vehicleid": "$vehicleid" },
          id: { $first: { _id: "$_id" } },
          points: { $push: "$points" }
      }
  },
 {
      $project: {
          _id: "$id._id",
          vehicleid: "$_id.vehicleid",
          points: "$points"
      }
  }
] ).pretty()
```

You get the following ***result***:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "vehicleid" : 32040,
        "points" : [
                {
                        "direction" : 135,
                        "latitude" : -3.744851,
                        "longitude" : -38.545571,
                        "odometer" : 55697826,
                        "routecode" : 0,
                        "speed" : 3,
                        "deviceid" : 134680,
                        "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T02:59:59Z")
                },
                {
                        "direction" : 135,
                        "latitude" : -3.235521,
                        "longitude" : -37.5122571,
                        "odometer" : 8456763,
                        "routecode" : 0,
                        "speed" : 4,
                        "deviceid" : 134680,
                        "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T05:35:59Z")
                }
        ]
}
```